# What's the best way to create a multi-page survey in Civi?

Tags: civisurvey

We'd like to survey our supporters with a Typeform-esque survey (simple questions, one per page). We'd also like to create a page within Civi so all the information is in one place.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: What CMS do you use? I've done multi-part surveys using Drupal's Webform Civi.

Answer (score 2):

There has been talk of supporting multi-step forms and wizards in FormBuilder. If you're interested in sponsoring that improvement, please get in touch on https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/dev-afform